# 'PeopleViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import *
from .serializers import *

class PeopleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    quaryset = Person.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from app import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('person', views.PeopleViewSet, basename='person')
urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I'm getting this error

'PeopleViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.

What is my mistake?

Comment: just change `quaryset = Person.objects.all()` with `queryset =Person.objects.all()`